# Add map marker at gmap center?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I'm fiddling around with GMap.NET.  I have a gmap.net map control on my form.  There is a red x (or plus sign, if you will) in the middle of the map.  I added a method that will put a marker wherever I click on the map.  However, the customer would rather have a "pushpin" button on the form that the user will click, and the marker will be added where the red X is located (which is always the center of the map control, it seems).  The map is drag-able and zoom-able, so the marker will be added wherever the red x is at that time.

[image]

Right now, when my program adds a marker, it translates the lat and lng from the `FromLocalToLatLng` gmap method:

```
private void gmap_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

        var lat = gmap.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat;
        var lng = gmap.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng;

        var markerOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");

        var marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new
            PointLatLng(lat, lng),
            GMarkerGoogleType.green_pushpin)
        {
            ToolTipText = "Kevin Jennings",
            ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.OnMouseOver
        };

        gmap.Overlays.Add(markerOverlay);
        markerOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
    }
```

In this case, though, I'm wondering if there's a way to add the marker at the map center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  You can get the center of the map by using the following code:

```
var center = gmap.Position;
```

Once I had the center, all I needed to do was add a marker at that position, like this:

```
var marker2 = new GMarkerGoogle(new
           PointLatLng(center.Lat, center.Lng),
           GMarkerGoogleType.green_pushpin)
       {
           ToolTipText = "Kevin Jennings",
           ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.OnMouseOver
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this

map.Zoom = 10;

map.Zoom = 9;

and your markers will position on the right direction..
complete code

```
        var lat = mapa.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat;
        var lng = mapa.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng;
        MessageBox.Show(lat + " long :" + lng);
        var markerOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");

        var marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new
            PointLatLng(lat, lng),
            GMarkerGoogleType.green_pushpin)
        {
            ToolTipText = "Ubicacion depto",
            ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.OnMouseOver
        };


        markerOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
        map.Overlays.Add(markerOverlay);
        map.Zoom = 10;
        map.Zoom = 9;
    }
```